# Is it possible to run detox tests in appcenter build

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center, detox

I am trying to run my detox tests via my appcenter build but having a bit of trouble, I have created an "appcenter-post-build.sh" script that should run the tests as I currently do locally.

it looks like this

```
brew tap wix/brew
brew install applesimutils
npm install -g react-native-cli
npm install -g detox-cli
brew tap facebook/fb
brew install fbsimctl --HEAD

if [ "$platform" == "ios" ];
then
   detox test --configuration ios.appcenter.debug --take-screenshots failing --cleanup
else
   detox test --configuration android.appcenter.debug --take-screenshots failing --cleanup
fi
```

I also have added a configuration to package.json which looks like

```
detox": {
"configurations": {
  "ios.appcenter.debug": {
    "binaryPath": "/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HGEMGo-crotfzqsahaubjcqbuyxzjoxbmjt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/HGEMGo/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/HGEMGo.app",
    "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/HGEMGo.xcworkspace -scheme HGEMGo -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
    "type": "ios.simulator",
    "name": "iPhone 11"
  },
```

For now i have hardcoded the binary path to where i think the app file is dropped when built , i would like to update this to a more relative path or maybe a process of copying the file to a suitable location in the future.

but when the above script gets executed in the appcenter, I have gathered a few of the errors I am seeing in the logs

```
field CFBundleIdentifier not found inside Info.plist of app binary at /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HGEMGo-crotfzqsahaubjcqbuyxzjoxbmjt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/HGEMGo/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/HGEMGo.app

ReferenceError: device is not defined

ReferenceError: element is not defined
```

Comment: The appcenter does not officially support it. But people have found a way around. https://github.com/patniko/detox-appcenter and https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/262 should be helpful.